# JavaFX TreeView adding item to the treeview results the same behavior of the two cells

Tags: javafx, treeview, treecell

I am willing to parse an XML Schema Definition and get the TreeView from the parsed file , then adding and removing items from the TreeView before generating an XML .

My issue is when i want to add a TreeItem from a selected one -duplicating it- results in a misbehavior of the two TreeItems : the selected one and the new one.

For example expanding one TreeItem results in expanding the other also .

SchemaTreeCell.java

```
public class SchemaTreeCell extends TreeCell<SchemaElement> {
GridPane grid = new GridPane();

private JFXButton bt ;
private ContextMenu detailsMenu ;
private TreeItem<SchemaElement> newItem;
private MenuItem showItem ;
private MenuItem addMenuItem;
private MenuItem deleteItem;
public SchemaTreeCell() {
    showItem = new MenuItem("Show Details");
    addMenuItem = new MenuItem("Add Element");
    deleteItem = new MenuItem("Remove Element");
    detailsMenu = new ContextMenu();
    detailsMenu.getItems().add(showItem);
    detailsMenu.getItems().add(addMenuItem);
    detailsMenu.getItems().add(deleteItem);
    bt = new JFXButton("Commit");
    showAction();
    addAction();
    deleteAction();
}


protected void addAction() {
    addMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            String max = getItem().getMaxOccurs().equals("unbounded")? "100" : getItem().getMaxOccurs();
            if (numberOccurence(getTreeItem())>=Integer.parseInt(max)) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
                alert.setHeaderText("Be Careful");
                alert.setContentText("Verify the Max Occurence of this item");
                alert.show();
            }
            else {
                newItem = new TreeItem<>();
                newItem =  getTreeView().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                getTreeItem().getParent().getChildren().add(newItem);
                addMenuItem.setOnAction(null);      
                t.consume();

            }

        }

    });
}
@Override
protected void updateItem(SchemaElement item, boolean empty) {

    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        setGraphic(null);
        setText(null);
    }else {
    setText(item == null ? ""
            : item.getValue() == null ? "<" + item.getName() + "/>"
                    : "<" + item.getName() + ">" + item.getValue() + "<" + item.
    setContextMenu(detailsMenu);
    }
}
```

This is how i called the CellFactory

```
getSchemaView().setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<SchemaElement>, TreeCell<SchemaElement>>() {
        @Override
        public TreeCell<SchemaElement> call(TreeView<SchemaElement> list) {
            return new SchemaTreeCell();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the exact same `TreeItem` that is already selected to the tree. The `TreeItem` has the `expanded` state (and other state that you almost certainly do not want replicated), so if you expand this tree item, both representations will expand.

Instead, create a new tree item with the same value, and add it to the tree:

```
addMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
        String max = getItem().getMaxOccurs().equals("unbounded")? "100" : getItem().getMaxOccurs();
        if (numberOccurence(getTreeItem())>=Integer.parseInt(max)) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setHeaderText("Be Careful");
            alert.setContentText("Verify the Max Occurence of this item");
            alert.show();
        }
        else {
            newItem = createDeepCopy(getTreeView().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            getTreeItem().getParent().getChildren().add(newItem);
            addMenuItem.setOnAction(null);      
            t.consume();

        }

    }

});

// ...

private TreeItem<SchemaElement> createDeepCopy(TreeItem<SchemaElement> original) {
    TreeItem<SchemaElement> copy = new TreeItem<SchemaElement>(original.getValue());
    for (TreeItem<SchemaElement> child : original.getChildren()) {
        copy.getChildren().add(createDeepCopy(child));
    }
    return copy ;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but your suggestion adds only a leaf TreeItem without children and not expandable . I want to deplicate the TreeItem but without the states you mentioned ..

Comment: @BilelNebli Edited answer.